# Some Brackets content not showing

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I have a problem where some of my background-images show in Live Preview but when viewing through Chrome itself, my background-images don't show. Here is a bit of the code with the images that don't show:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(../pictures/s1.jpg);"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(../pictures/s2.jpg);"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(../pictures/s3.jpg);"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

Comment: have you tried giving the specific route to the images? Or have you tried using a tilde (`~`) to describe the root path?

Comment: This part of the code `<div class="fill" style="background-image:url(../pictures/s1.jpg);"></div>` might be causing the issue? Why don't you directly use normal img tags?

Comment: Thank you @Satej S, turns out url(../pictures/s1.jpg) should be url(pictures/s1.jpg) which is a bit strange because you have to go to root first before entering pictures folder but that fixed the problem

Comment: @Feyt , glad to know the problem is fixed.Any particular reason you're using background images and not normal image tags?

Comment: I thought of putting some text over it but in the end did not. Thank you @Satej S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the easiest way:

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item"><img src="assets/img/slide1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/slide2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/slide3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
```

If you want to use the `background-image` attribute, then you should try:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item one"></div>
        <div class="item two"></div>
        <div class="item three"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;

}
.carousel .one {
    background: url(../pictures/s1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .two {
    background: url(../pictures/s2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .three {
    background: url(../pictures/s3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant reply @EliTownsend. Turns out the url(../pictures/s1.jpg) should be url(pictures/s1.jpg) which is a bit strange because you have to enter root first.